# Angular4 : How to merge three project which has two different bootstrap version

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have three projects (`website`, `employer`, and `admin`). All of them are base on `Angular4.4.4`. It is almost complete. But I want to merge all of them and make it one project. I proceed according to following structure.

First, I made another empty fresh project, and add `website`, `admin`, and  `employer` as a module inside of this project. the routes look like this.

```
 {
    path: '', 
    loadChildren:"./website/website.module#WebsiteModule"  
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'feed',
    loadChildren: 'app/website/feed/feed.module#FeedModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'employer',
    loadChildren: './employer/employer.module#EmployerModule',
  },
```

Now, The problem is that `website` use `Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6`, `admin` use `Bootstrap v3.3.7`, and `employer` use same as admin `Bootstrap v3.3.7`

So my question is, is there any way to use that specific version of bootstrap for specific modules?

If not, what is the best way to merge it.

Comment: these are three modules and not three modules can you elaborate more please

Comment: I have updated my question. I do not get your point.

Comment: you are mentioning that three different projects but your code seems to contain one project three modules

Comment: Yes, I want to make the project as a module because I want to merge all my project into one project.

Comment: Well, `Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6` is completely and totally OUTDATED! It's almost as outdated as the dinosaurs...

Answer (score 3):

I recently merged my project form Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4. Only a few styles got messed up. Then I followed bootstrap's migrations guide https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/ to replace bootstrap classes. for Example `.panel` to `.card`. It took about 2 days for a medium-sized project. But it totally worth it.

If you don't want to in this way. Just include bootstrap CSS files in each section module separately. And let the web pack take care of bundling your modules.

Comment: I wanna go with second way, how to include css on each section of module?

Answer (score 0):

bring all the projects modules in on project and then fix the routing.
remove bootstrap scripts and styles from angular-cli or webpack and put them inside each respective modules.

Comment: How to put bootstrap on respective modules.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Bootstrap 4 is the beta 3.

Compared to `beta 3` the `alpha 6` version feels like a dinosaur version. There were even breaking changes between the beta 3 version and the beta 2 version.

Luckily, the next Bootstrap 4 version will be the final release and that will NOT introduce any breaking changes anymore.

So, `Bootstrap 4 beta 3` is what you want to focus on right now.